# How to Revert back the ODI Code changes in Oracle Data Integrator 12C

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

seeking for solution of Reverting the ODI code changes. How to see the Options for reverting the ODI Code

Answer (score 1):

Once you saved your object, you can't revert the code. 
The solution is to connect your ODI environment with some versioning tool, like SVN and save periodically your work.

For more info, refer to [ODI with VCS](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/develop/vcs.htm)